# Grouping Feature on Duplicate Posts instead of flagging to Stop Discouraging Rookies

Tags: feature-request

A lot of times questions are flagged as duplicate and I have no quarrel about that. But a lot of times, rookies find themselves with a flagged question that because it does not address their problem specific with their code and used technology or what ever surroundings and kind of makes them afraid of asking any more questions and that can be a problem. They need specific answer even though their question points to a clearly duplicate post.

The problem is that by flagging these questions, these new users may get discouraged to even asking new questions. This problem has to be solved. How can a community like this have a feature that discourages asking questions. I get it that somehow you have to regulate questions and the way they are asked, but make it in a more friendly way, with Green Flags rather than with Red Flags, maybe.

What if instead of flagging question as duplicates we mark them as syndromes(
questions) or a grouping feature, so our guy who posted the question can see a little message below: "see also similar questions to yours ... " suggested by the same person who would have otherwise flag the question?

Comment: That is how duplicates work already.

Comment: Yea but the end result for the person asking the question is definitely not the same. Their specific possibly duplicate question ends up not being actually answered but redirected to other posts. For rookies this can be a serious problem. No body actually helped them by redirecting to duplicates. They need a more personal help. Flagging their question gets them scarred of asking questions anymore. And let the flagging for Duplicate if it really cant be made a Grouping Feature be non-destructive for their reputation points.

Comment: They are supposed to edit their question to show what kind of help they really need.  Then it can be reopened again and get an answer.  But sure, that doesn't always happen, resources are finite here.  There are another ten thousand users that want help and didn't get this wrong, they'll get ahead of the line.  SO needs twice as many contributors to keep up with the work load, they don't grow on trees.

Comment: My problem is with the way Flagging a Duplicate works is that it discourages rookies to ask questions. This aspect should not affect newbies reputation and emotional opinion about stackOverflow. Give them two duplicate flags and you scared them for life. The'll run like crazy from this site.

Comment: @ISS Users shouldn't see duplicates as a bad thing. Closed duplicate questions can be good signposts for users looking for answers. Maybe we should make that more clear.

Comment: @ISS And why should duplicate flags scare them? After all they are pointing at solutions.

Comment: @HansPassant You really should make this clear. It made me not want to ask questions any more. It was like: ok this is a duplicate question, should have not asked it. I got flagged. Oh boy..  Its like they have done something wrong for asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @ISS Note that asking duplicate questions can lead to downvotes nevertheless. A user asking a question that has been asked hundreds of times before can seem to have neglected doing enough research.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah but we need to be more forgiving and welcoming with new users that don't know about good researched questions. Otherwise we loose them. When they are older users, you may punish them by affecting their reputation score, why not, but don't do this to a one week old user.

Comment: Why do we need to be more lenient?  They have loads of documentation put in front of them to read and absorb. It's pretty clear that we expect to see research effort; their inability to actually do that *should* lead to downvotes.  It is, after all, a question that does not meet our standards.

Comment: @ISS Did you mean to adress me? The first thing new users should learn is that doing research is expected and valued at Stack Overflow. They don't learn this by being treated differently than older users. And close votes and downvotes are not punishment; they are meant to signal that a post has problems and should be improved.

Comment: @fbueckert Let's be honest when you first signed up with this website is that what you did in the second minute, reading loads of documentations and a lot of researching so you can ask the Golden Question?

Comment: @ISS Yes.  Yes, I did, because I was joining a new community, with rules I was unfamiliar with.  That's common decency.  But none of that changes the fact that we judge *content*.  Whether it's from a new user or an old-timer; they're **all** held to the same standards.  If new users want to be welcomed, they can display the same qualities as old-timers and read and understand the rules.

Comment: @ModusTollens I guess so. From a psychological perspective flagging a rookie is discouraging him to ask and learn something new. Signal it in a more friendly way just so he may learn in a constructive way where we feels welcomed and not intimidated by established users.

Comment: @ISS I did so too, of course. It is polite to get aquainted with a community before joining. It has been part of online communities for a long time.

Comment: @ISS Two problems with that. 1) it will set wrong expections. The new user will not understand why there's a change in treatment when they aren't new any more. 2) Other new users will see problematic posts and assume that they can post like that as well.

Comment: @fbueckert I didn't. Maybe it's my culture maybe I was to excited about the idea of being able to ask a question so I'll get lots of lots of answers.So I am supposed no to be welcomed just because my cultural background is different? That's way in society we have rules for minority. So we can protect them and care fort them so they can integrate in our community.

Comment: @ModusTollens I don's suggest to stop discouraging "bad" behavior but make it in a way that it does not discourage new users for asking questions at all.

Comment: @ISS If you don't read the rules, tell me why you should get *any* leniency?  You have to click a checkbox at the end when you first join that says, "I read this and I understand it".  You're now telling us you didn't?  How is that supposed to help us accommodate you, when you've obviously done nothing to accommodate us?

Comment: @ISS Who said you would not be welcomed? You are as welcome as any user. You will be treated as friendly as anybody else. You will be pointed to helpful advice. But if you believe a downvote or a flag is hostile and unfriendly, that is your interpretation. You are not judged as a person, but your post should follow the basic guidelines.

Comment: @ModusTollens No you're wrong here. I am not treated as any other user if I am a new user. That's the problem here. New users are lacking a lot of privileges. So if I don't have the same right, why should I have the same rules? This is not fair at all. Same rights, same rules. Now that seems fair to me. So if I am lacking right why not indulge me for a while if am I doing something wrong? Tell me without flagging my duplicate question.

Comment: @ISS Please keep in mind that users here are volunteers, and there are many questions asked each day. It's in _your_ best interest making interacting with your post as easy as possible, because if a question is badly researched or missing information, there are lots of other questions right around the corner that _are_ on topic and complete.

Comment: @ISS I started with 1 reputation here as well. You will get the same "rights" as I have right now eventually. Nothing unfair here at all.

Comment: When it comes to asking questions, you have **exactly** the same privileges as anybody else.  All the privileges do is help volunteers moderate the site.  Which, with enough investment, anyone can get.  Same rules, same privileges.

Comment: @ModusTollens I got it. Flag it with Green or Yellow instead of Red. Lead me to similar posts, but don't affect my reputation. If else, why not giving negative score to new users just because ... ?

Comment: How is it red in the first place?  New users won't see any flag notification box, and the duplicate comment or automated message isn't red.  So I'm confused why you think it's, "red".  As for negative score, well, that's usually for research effort.  If a duplicate is easily found, why *shouldn't* it be downvoted?  Keep in mind that the poster being a new user is irrelevant; votes are on the post, not who posted it.

Comment: @ISS I know you don't mean it like that, but to me you come ascross as asking for special treatment because you can't be bothered to read and follow the rules of the community. Please don't give up and give it a chance. It's worth a little research.

Comment: This is all I remember about last Duplicate Flag: Red, less reputation points. It's about not why you do it, but rather how you do it. This is what I mean

Comment: @ISS Having a question closed doesn't change your reputation at all.

Comment: @ISS: "*So I am supposed no to be welcomed just because my cultural background is different?*" This is not about your "cultural background". It's about the purpose of this site, and whether your question helps to fulfill it. Questions are either appropriate or not appropriate. A duplicate may be useful, but it does not need to be answered, since it already has been answered.

Comment: What I am saying is that maybe a dublicate even though already been answered may not solve the problem. Since there might be slight implementation differences, it might not make sense in the mind of a rookie. So why affect his reputation for his lack of skills, understanding or whatever..?

Comment: @ISS If a duplicate does not solve the asker's problem, the onus is on the asker to tell us **why** it didn't solve their problem.  We can't read minds, so if all we get is a common error message, without evidence of research, the best we can do is close it as a duplicate.  If the asker wants us to do more, then they have to do more.

Comment: @fbueckert they won't do more if they feel punished in any way. That's how human psichology works...

Comment: @ISS Then they don't do more.  They have to adapt to us; treating them with kid gloves does nothing but cause issues further down the line.  They are subject to the same rules and regulations as everybody else; there is no special treatment.  As soon as we have to give new users special treatment, then the site as we know it is dead, and quality has nowhere to go but down.

Comment: @fbueckert how can you tell that? Do you have data and strong arguments to base your hypothesis on or is that just a mere guess?

Comment: Because quality and standards are what set us apart from the rest of the internet.  Hence why experts like to congregate here.  That's why people like to ask questions and get help here; this is where the experts are.  As soon as new users are no longer required to meet those standards, experts leave; they want good, interesting questions to answer, and the thirty thousandth homework question isn't that, at all.  And without experts, *nobody* gets their questions answered.  Quality = experts.  No quality = no experts.

Comment: I think the bigger question is, why are new users important enough to ignore the rules?  What sets them apart, and lets them get away with not reading our rules, or meeting our standards?

Comment: I am no expert but I was able to answer a question and the person who asked it said I am awesome. So, do I have to leave because I an not an answer or just stick to the asking part and rirk loosing my reputation? That's a though choice one has to make. And about special treatment, some users already do enjoy it. So it's not fair. And I don't think it would be unfair for new users to enjoy a little break when it comes to immediately get their first questions affecting reputation.

Comment: Please dont generalize the question. This only about how the highlighted problem could make someone new feel, and not about braking rules and not meeting standards.

Comment: "Fair"?  What is, "fair"?  All content is held to the same standards.  Who wrote is **irrelevant**.  Users that have been here a while are better at writing better content, so there's less chance of it being downvoted.  New users have a buttload of introductory information put in front of them before they can first post.  What's not, "fair", is them ignoring all of it, and expecting their post to be immune to our standards.  That's pretty rude on their part, wouldn't you say?

Comment: You might be right who knows. I'd be arogant to say I know all the facts and do completely understand the big picture. But then is this the only way that works? What if things and processes could be improved? Would someone be opened to experimenting with that?

Comment: But things and processes ARE constantly being improved, and debatable things are constantly being debated. What you suggest however is not an improvement, as you can see from the community reaction to your question. And once again, note that this reaction has nothing to do with you, the reception for the idea would be the same if someone with 50k reputation suggested it. I bet most of the people who vote on these questions don't even check the person who posted it before voting. They act purely based on content, as we should.

Comment: @Roope I think it is fair to make the point that most of the time these suggestions do come from low rep users.... Now of course the voting isn't BECAUSE they are new, but the data might look skewed that way anyway

Comment: @Patrice Yes, I agree, but as you know it is merely a prime example of correlation without causation, and our goal is to politely explain this so the new users instead of pampering them. This online community is essentially a subset of the "real-life" professional community, while the new users are often hobbyists (who are most welcome to use the resource). Thus, we expect similar conduct as we would expect from any new hire in the "real life", and the goal is to communicate this expectation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Voting to close a question and downvoting it are two entirely separate actions.  Neither are new users given a free pass; they want the help, they have to accept the rules.

Duplicates are meant to help the asker, after all; the question's already been asked, and answered, so it gets them an answer much faster, along with anyone else who might ask that question the same way.

Downvotes are to show future usefulness, and levels of effort.  If a question is an easily found duplicate, it *should* be downvoted; it means the asker didn't make much of an effort to search, and the question won't be of much use in the future whatsoever.  It also sends a strong signal that similar future contributions are not acceptable.

Notice how neither of those actions pertain to new or established users; our actions are done to the content, and the content alone.  We have high standards here, and we do our best to maintain them.  That means everyone is held to the same level, whether they've been here since the beginning, or joined today.

Comment: You might be right even though I am not entirely agreeing your answer. I got ya bro. Thanks!

Answer (score -22):

I'd definitely allow inappropriate questions or duplicate posts to be asked without any penalties on user's reputation. Let the user feel free and welcomed to ask and not hindered or scared he might do something wrong.

Comment: Feels like kind of a pipe dream. But nothing stops you from setting up your own site with this and see how it picks up :). Best of luck in that endeavor. Still feel entirely welcome to post here (after due diligence research, of course)